# spark dataset overwrite particular partition not working in spark 2.4

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

In my job final step is to store the executed data in Hive table with partition on "date" column.
Sometime, due to job fail, I need to re-run job for particular partition alone.
As observed, when I use below code, spark overrides all the partitions when using overwrite mode.

```
ds.write.partitionBy("date").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("test.someTable")
```

After going through multiple blogs and stackoverflow, I followed below steps to overwrite particular partitions only.

```
Step 1: Enbable dynamic partition for overwrite mode
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverWriteMode", "dynamic")

Step 2: write dataframe to hive table using saveToTable

Seq(("Company1", "A"), 
("Company2","B"))
.toDF("company", "id")
.write
.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
.partitionBy("id")
.saveAsTable(targetTable)

spark.sql(s"SELECT * FROM ${targetTable}").show(false)
spark.sql(s"show partitions ${targetTable}").show(false)

Seq(("CompanyA3", "A"))
.toDF("company", "id")
.write
.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
.insertInto(targetTable)

spark.sql(s"SELECT * FROM ${targetTable}").show(false)
spark.sql(s"show partitions ${targetTable}").show(false)
```

Still it overwrite all the partitions.[image]
[image]

As per this blog, https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-sql/apache-spark-sql-hive-insertinto-command/read, "insertinto" should overwrite only particular partitions

If I create table first and then use "insertinto" method, it working fine

Set required configuration,
[image]
Step 1: Create table

[image]

Step 2: Add data using insertinto method
[image]

Step 3: Overwrite paritition
[image]

I wanted to know, what is difference between creating hive table via SaveToTable and creating table manually? Why it is not working in first scenario? 
Could any one help me in this?

Comment: Worked some time ago, will need to investigate, will get back.

Comment: Interesting in that some time ago my deleted answer worked. Not sure what to make of that.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you please share again deleted answer?

Comment: I got it to work now. I am looking after dinner what the difference is with your code. Things have changed. Are you runnin gin Notebook or spark shell or compiled program???

Comment: Am running in spark-shell

Comment: OK just had dindins, so am seeing what the difference is. Will get back.

Comment: Got it, just a typo that fooled us.

Comment: I thought that it has something to do whether our hive table is external or managed... but not sure... the docs suggest that this option does not affect Hive tables : https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/dc5ebc2d5b8122121d89a9175737bea95ae10126/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/internal/SQLConf.scala#L1983

Comment: I tested also without Hive settings afair.

Comment: I think the answer, no matte how trivial,.is in fact correct. Or do you have proof otherwise?

Comment: so what is your conclusion?

Comment: I am facing the same issue with spark 2.4.5 and hive external table. If I create the table manually and run insertInto in dynamic partition mode, it works as expected. But when spark creates the external table, and the next time when you run insertInto, all the old partitions get lost. When comparing the DDLs there were some spark related metadata like version, catalog that was present in the spark created table but was not found in the manual one. IMHO, that might be the reason. Anybody any luck to get this to work all via spark?

Answer (score 0):

Try with lowercase w!

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic")
```

not

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverWriteMode", "dynamic")
```

It fooled me. You have 2 variations in use in your scripting if you look.

My original answer deprecated it appears.

Comment: strange, the docs suggest that for Hive tables, this is always dynamic : https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/dc5ebc2d5b8122121d89a9175737bea95ae10126/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/internal/SQLConf.scala#L1983

Comment: @Raphael Roth. I tested it. Triply.

Comment: goo to know... working with external hive tables, I've never used this option and it worked fine (but using spark <2.3)

Comment: @Raphael Roth. In the past it was a little different and spark hive has some nuances as u know. I checked now with databricks and asker with spark shell. The mysterious things of spark like the partition preserve question u answered for me.